# Jquery Ajax Trying to get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get this ajax o work on the first button, on the second button I am just trying to see if I at least hit the jquery but this is not happening for some reason, my code is as follows.

```
<form id="postform" >
                 <input class="btn btn-lg" style="border: 1px solid gray;" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required> &nbsp
                 <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="emailbutton" onsubmit="submitting()" type="submit">Submit</button>
                 <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit" id="#inputbutton" value="Shooter" ></input>
             </form>
             <script>
             (function ($) {
                 function submitting(e) 
                 {
                    e.preventDeafault();
                     $('#emailbutton').on('submit', (function () {
                         alert("Clicked");
                         $.ajax
                         ({
                             type: 'POST',
                             url: 'bootstrap/php/form.php',
                             data: $(this).serialize(),
                             success: function (result) {
                                 console.log(result);
                                 $('#postform').html(result);
                             }
                         });
                     }));
                 }

                 function subshooter() {
                 $('#inputbutton').click(function() { alert('testbutton clicked'); });
                 }

             });
             </script>
```

My main aim to get the ajax working so when people submit their email address on a form the resulting ajax will process a php file and the html will change to something like "Thank You" without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: Note that the correct method name is `preventDefault()`, and that you don't appear to call `subshooter()` anywhere?

Comment: I changed the spelling still didn't help

Comment: PhilVarg I tried the edits you suggested it's still not hitting the functions I am at my wits end here

Comment: Thanks guys, with the corrections to the code it was still telling me that "$" was undefined the reason for this was because I wrote the function first and loaded the jQuery file at the bottom of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified Html

```
<form id="postform" >
                 <input class="btn btn-lg" style="border: 1px solid gray;" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required> &nbsp
                 <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="emailbutton"  type="submit">Submit</button>
                 <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit" id="inputbutton" value="Shooter" ></input>
             </form>
```

your script have so many errors that is the reason why it is failed... in future always check browser console...

corrected js:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
                 $('#inputbutton').on('click',function() { alert('testbutton clicked'); });
                 $('#postform').on('submit',function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            alert("Clicked");
                            $.ajax({
                                     type: 'POST',
                                     url: "bootstrap/php/form.php",
                                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                                     success: function (result) {
                                         console.log(result);
                                          alert("success");
                                         $('#postform').html(result);
                                     },
                                     error: function (){
                                        alert("Unable To post");
                                     }
                                 }); 
                    });
});
             </script>
```

Comment: Thanks I did use the console in developer tools in google chrome but there weren't any errors that were showing up in the console. Could you please explain where the errors in my code was.

Comment: error 1 : e.preventDefault();   $('#emailbutton').on('submit' instead of this you should have used $('#emailbutton').on('click'     or directly         $('#postform').on('submit'  and one more thing do not name id as '#something' you did this id='#inputbutton' instead of this use id='inputbutton'

Comment: Silly mistakes eh, thanks for pointing them out ravi teja Kaveti

Answer (score 0):

When `submitting` gets called, it is attaching a click event to the button, but that event has already happened, so it would not get called again until the Submit button has been clicked again.

Likewise, `preventDeafault` is misspelled and most likely causing execution to stop.

Another problem is that you are not passing in an event to submitting, so `e` will be undefined.

Since you are using jQuery, you should attach the event using jQuery, which will give you access to the event and the `preventDefault` function:

```
$('form').submit( function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code:

```
                         <script>

                        (function ($) {


                         $('#inputbutton').click(function() { 
                         alert('testbutton clicked'); });

                     });

                         function submitting(e) 
                         {
                            e.preventDefault();
                             $('#emailbutton').on('submit', (function () {
                                 alert("Clicked");
                                 $.ajax
                                 ({
                                     type: 'POST',
                                     url: 'bootstrap/php/form.php',
                                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                                     success: function (result) {
                                         console.log(result);
                                         $('#postform').html(result);
                                     }
                                 });
                             }));
                         }
                         </script>
```

Mistakes that you made:

the function to prevent default is  `e.preventDefault();`

In jquery you should bind the click event to the button on page load.

Since  `submitting(e)` is a function it should be outside the onbody load event i.e `document.ready({ ... })` function.

Comment: thanks. onbody load? I though (function ($) ...) was short hand for the document.ready function

Comment: yes it a short hand for document.ready, but it is an event that is called when the body of your web document is loaded.